# Wifi not connecting Broadcom wireless

Tags: wireless

I am new to Linux, so still don't understand much.  Last week I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on my laptop with a dual boot configuration with Windows 7.  At first, the wireless setup was not working.  After reading and searching the web, I found in the Broadcom website a Linux driver for the wireless device to be setup in Linux.  I followed the instructions, and after 30 minutes I finally got the driver installed and the wireless setup appeared in the menus.  I configured it to find my wifi, found it, but after a million tries, it keeps asking for the password and never connects.  I tested it on Windows, and I connect perfectly.  Then I disabled the security in my wifi router (turned off the WPA/WEP security) and voila, the network connected in Ubuntu Linux.  When I turn the security back on, it goes back to square one, asking for the password in a never ending cycle.  I have searched everywhere on this problem, found a lot of people have encountered the same issue, followed their steps to fix the connection, but still no avail.  I have reconfigured the network settings, driver, my router, and nothing. I doesnt want to accept the WEP/WPA security settings at all. Anyone have an easy fix other than the complex ones I have found on the web?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the driver that you installed, if do you have a fresh ubuntu install without data, please reinstall it, else try to uninstall the driver.
2. Assuming that do you have a wired, connection, connect it.
3. Install the package `b43-fwcutter` from the Software Center or with the command `sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter`
4. Reboot